# ngModel 2-way binding not assigning after following the documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, ngmodel

My html file has the following in it:

```
<form (submit)="register()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name='username' placeholder="Enter your username" [(ngModel)]="userData.username">
```

In my ts file for the same component I have:

```
userData: any = {};
```

Finally, in my app.module.ts I have:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
    ...,
    imports: [ ... FormsModule, ...],
    ...})
```

According to everything I've read, that is sufficient to have the data in my .ts file update, but it is not currently. I've tried manually updating ngModelChange seperately than the model (and updating the [] and () accordingly), changing names across the html file, removing elements from html and adding them back to find if something isn't working, and several other desperation tricks, but can't seem to figure out why this isn't properly binding.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you logged `userData` at breakpoints to see what it actually contains?

Comment: Hello, i reproduced your same code in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vrcs9z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) , if you implemented all of your code correctly, you shall not have any problem (look at my stackblitz example) , else that, you have to share all of your code to check if there is a problem or an error

Comment: I'm running your exact example in my environment Misha I still have the same problem somehow. In Stackblitz it runs perfectly as expected.

Comment: I removed implementing the ngOnInit and it fixed my problem. Not if that is the intended functionality (that ngOnInit modules can't have ngModel properties), but that seems to be the case for me

Answer (score -1):

Form control and ngModel shouldn't be implemented at the same time. If you're going to implement a form group, then use a form control. Otherwise, use ngModel.

Comment: that's not true, you can use both ngModel and Form controls inside Form Group even if you use Reactive Forms, you can only do that when you specify this option `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`, in addition, he did not implement Form Group in his code, he just named a class with `class="form-group"`

Comment: It's not recommended for higher angular.